# add multiple (decimals) values from two tables to update a third

Tags: mysql

This SHOULD be trivial but I am going round in circles, perhaps someone can help.

I have two tables (T1, T2) from which I wish to extract a number of values in each row and update the contents of a third table (T3) iff (if and only if) two UQ, NN fields in T1, T2 match, in which case I want to add some of the values in the corresponding rows from T1, T2 together and put them in T3 and copy some other values over to T3.

The fields to be summed are all declared DECIMAL.

Simplified and in pseudocode (to avoid making too many assumptions):

```
SELECT T1.a,T1.b,T1.c from T1

SELECT T2.d, T2.e from T2

UPDATE T3.col1=a, T3.col2=b, T3.col3 = (value of(T2.c) + value of(T2.e)) iff T1.a = T2.d
```

A variety of attempts have failed to work.

I am running MySQL Workbench 5.2.37 on Ubuntu 12.10

---

Example from comment below:

```
UPDATE Test_join as T3 
  SELECT GZHident, Magnitude_1 from GZHTableExtended3 as T1 
  SELECT AHZid, DM from AHZDMConversionTable as T2 JOIN T2,T1 
    ON T1.GZHident = T2.AHZid 
SET T3.AHZid = T1.GZHident 
SET T3.DM = T2.DM 
SET T3.Abs_Magnitude_1 = T1.Magnitude_1 + T2.DM;
```

Comment: `A variety of attempts have failed to work.`  It would be helpful to show what your attempts have been so we don't repeat work that you've already tried.

Comment: Unfortunately I have discarded them. Let's start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports multi-table [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) using JOIN syntax, just like SELECT. This isn't standard ANSI SQL, but it's very useful for these types of situations.

Example:

```
UPDATE T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.a = T2.d
JOIN T3 ON ...???...
SET T3.col1=T1.a, 
    T3.col2=T1.b,
    T3.col3 = T2.c + T2.e;
```

You don't have enough information in your question for me to guess how to join to T3.

---

Thanks for posting an example UPDATE query. But it's still not clear how you want to update T3. The sample query you give is not valid SQL code at all. I suggest you read a tutorial on programming in SQL.

You seem be confused between UPDATE and INSERT?  Keep in mind:

- INSERT adds new rows.
- UPDATE changes values in existing rows.

I'm guessing from your wording, but perhaps you want to add new rows. You can do that in this way:

```
INSERT INTO Test_join (AHZid, DM, Abs_Magnitude)
SELECT T1.GZHident, T2.DM, T1.Magnitude_1 + T2.DM
FROM GZHTableExtended3 as T1
JOIN AHZDMConversionTable as T2 JOIN T2 
  ON T1.GZHident = T2.AHZid;
```

Comment: Strawberry, pubsee etc apologies, I missed your point and thought that using pseudocode would help rather than using my efforts all of which were clearly wrong.

Comment: Strawberry, pubsee, liyakat and others apologies, I misunderstood your point and thought that describing the problem in pseudocode would help rather than confusing matters with my efforts all of which were clearly wrong. @Bill I think that what I want to do in your terms amounts to update T3...There is no need to join T3 to anything as we are only updating T3

Comment: @PeterDz, yes I understand you are updating T3, using values from T1 and T2. But *which rows* from T1 and T2? That's what the join resolves. It would help if you edit your question with an example rows from each of T1, T2, and a "before and after" of rows of T3 that you want updated.

Comment: UPDATE Test_join as T3
 SELECT GZHident, Magnitude_1 from GZHTableExtended3 as T1 
 SELECT AHZid, DM from AHZDMConversionTable as T2
 JOIN T2,T1 ON T1.GZHident = T2.AHZid
  SET T3.AHZid=T1.GZHident
  SET T3.DM = T2.DM
  SET T3.Abs_Magnitude_1 = T1.Magnitude_1 + T2.DM;[br]